# JQuery multiselect UI how to exclude an option

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget). I want my list to have 5 options and the first one("Please Choose") to be selected by default, however I want only the last four options as to be visible and selectable from the users when the list is unfolded.Any good idea how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what exactly you want? You want 4 options to be hidden first?

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Consider the following code:                                  <select name="gender" id="gender">                            <option value "Choos">Choose</option>                               <option value="MAN">MAN</option>
<option value="WOMAN">WOMAN</option>
</select>                                                          I want "Choose" to be default selected and the list to show only MAN  WOMAN when unfolded. In other words I do not want the first option to appear inside the list, only to be default selected the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You must have checked the documentation of that plugin, it has everything to customize it in all possible manner. Check out below sample code:

**HTML**

```
<select name="gender" id="gender"  multiple="multiple"> 
    <option value="MAN">MAN</option> 
    <option value="WOMAN">WOMAN</option> 
</select>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").multiselect({
      noneSelectedText: 'Choose Options'
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XVu33/)